# Convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss in R

Tags: r

My data contains some date fields in this format yyyy-mm-dd

```
    id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    d1 <- c("2001-01-01", "1999-12-01","2007-11-31", "1995-05-01", "2013-01-07")
    datadd <- data.frame(id,d1)
```

I need to convert date field d1 to the following format mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss
So the data looks like:

```
id  d1  
1   1/1/2001 0:00:00
2   12/1/1999 0:00:00
3   11/13/2007 0:00:00
4   5/1/1995 0:00:00
5   1/7/2013 0:00:00
```

Comment: What is the `class` of the date fields? The answer will vary depending. In your example, `d1` will be a `factor`.

Comment: Are you sure you want `1/1/2001` and not `01/01/2001`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `strptime` (or `as.Date`) and `format`:

```
> format(strptime(datadd$d1, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "01/01/2001 00:00:00" "12/01/1999 00:00:00" "11/13/2007 00:00:00"
[4] "05/01/1995 00:00:00" "01/07/2013 00:00:00"

## format(as.Date(datadd$d1), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I suppose you can use some `gsub` too if you want to remove the leading zeroes for single digit days and months.

Answer (score 3):

the `lubridate`package is your friend. It's really intuitive.

```
## install and launch the {lubridate} package
> dt <- "1/1/2001 0:10:00"  
> dt2 <- mdy_hms(dt)
[1] "2001-01-01 00:10:00 UTC"
```